# How can i add overlay hover on slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would appreciate little help on this.

I wanna add an image/text overlay hover on images of this slider below. 
So when someone's hovering the image will appear a 50% transparent black block and the "details" image/text in the middle.

This is an example of hovering (the zoom and details buttons) : http://themes.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/Lola-Html-Theme/Light/

This is the slider I wanna use : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Alzhn

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, that's why im asking here.
This is what i've done till now: http://jsfiddle.net/ionmihai/y9L3t/4/

And this is a live on my host : http://ionmihai.co.nr/IMSlider

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel.  Consider the following projects:

- http://wowslider.com/jquery-slideshow-huge-demo.html
- http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

For overlays, you can also consider

- http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/

Try any of the above links for implementation and be more specific with your question.

For example, I am having issue with X, I want to do Y and I have tried solving this using XYZ. Your JS fiddle is just a copy of your existing project with no indication of what you have tried to solve your problem.

As with any learning environment, I would take small steps first.  In your use case, I would tackle the problem as follows:

1. Require on hover caption
2. Require slider

Then when step#1 is completed, you can build on top of that and so forth.